# sum values from database in DJANGO templatetags

Tags: django

```
{% for fine in subjects%}
   
 {{ fine.points }}
    
{% endfor %}
```

as a result of repetition values are generated for example 15.2 | 12.3 | 15.2 | 14.1
I need to collect all the values , should be added all values
i know you need to use a `sum` filter for this

```
    from django import template
    
    register = template.Library()
    
@register.filter
def running_total(fine_list):
    return sum(d.get('fine_sum') for d in fine_list)
```

i wrote such an algorithm, but unfortunately this does not work

Comment: how to collect values

Comment: how to collect repetitive values

Comment: Please read the following documentation: [SO Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & [On Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). And then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65964265/edit), and rephrase the question, providing a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), with code, data, errors, current & expected output, as [formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: @DavirovBakhodir, share also your model. If I understood correctly, points are Many2ManyField? And you want to get the sum of all points?

Comment: Yeah you are understood correctly